# jScrollPane - doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I'm trying to use jScrollPane, but it does not work.

I'm putting the scripts in the head section

```
<link href="jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="myFile.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Then I have a  element (with a table in the content)

```
<div class="scroll-pane">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

and in myFile.js i put:

```
$(function () {
   $(".scroll-pane").jScrollPane();
});
```

My error is:

> Object does not support the property or method "getElementsByTagName"

I'm using jQuery v1.5 and jScrollPane - v2.0.0beta11 - 2011-07-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use another jQuery version (1.7) and it is working - don't know why.

Apparently jQuery v1.5 and jScrollPane - v2.0.0beta11 - 2011-07-04 are not working together.